# Getting response before firebase transaction done

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, callback, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to retrieve all the child then when there's match display.
I print the value in the console and my code work well there after few second, but when I print it in the agent as a  message it show not available before the response because it does not wait.
Here is my code:

```
function retrieveContact(agent) {
  var query = admin.database().ref("/contacts").orderByKey();
  query.once("value")
    .then(function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
            var key = childSnapshot.key;
            var childName = childSnapshot.child('name').val();
            if (agent.parameters.name == childName) {

                console.log('find ' + childName);
                agent.add('The email address for ' + childName + ' is ' + childSnapshot.child('email').val());

            }
            // console.log('testMode'+childName);
        }); //// .then 
    }); //// .once }
```

SO, how can I wait my response then let the agent show the result? 
How can I include the promise concept in my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show your entire Handler function, but if you're doing async operations (such as reading from the firebase db) you **must** return the Promise. This is how the Handler Dispatcher knows to wait for the Promise to complete before returning a response to the user.

In your case, it is probably as simple as

```
return query.once("value")
  // etc
```